# Python : dosomethinghere().dependent().on().thismethod()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

If I write code like this I can chain together method calls on an Object instance :

```
class ChainClassTest(object):
    def order_by(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("I'm in order_by")
        return self

    def filter_by(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("I'm in filter_by")
        return self

    def get_list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("I'm in get_list")
        return self


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cct = ChainClassTest()
    cct.get_list().filter_by().order_by()
```

but what I'd like to be able to is have the `get_list()` call do something dependent upon a value set by `order_by` . Of course by the time `order_by` is being executed `get_list` has already completed execution and so I can't do that . Or can I ?

I've thought about getting the `get_list`, `filter_by`, `order_by` and other similar methods to update a stack of function calls and then execute them all at the end ... except of course there's no way of knowing that you're at the end.

This would allow that to happen

```
cct.get_list().filter_by().order_by()
cct.now_actually_do_it()
```

Where `now_actually_do_it` consumed the stack of functions created by the previous line of code but I would really like to be able to do this on one line.

---

**EDIT 1**: Just to be clear I only mentioned the `now_actually_do_it` as an indication of how it might be done but I really don't want to do it that way .

Comment: If you want to implement that, you would not `return self` but return some kind of StatementBuilder instance that collects all the parameters until you `now_actually_do_it`.

Comment: @Thilo : thanks for your comment but the key thing is I *don't* want to use a "now_actually_do_it" type method if I can possibly avoid it.

Comment: Wouldn't you just call it in a different order `cct.filter_by().order_by().get_list()`. Have`get_list` return a list rather than self. Making it the end of any chaining.

Comment: Would it be do bad if the actuallydoit method was just appended to the end of the chain? It's a pretty popular pattern. Otherwise you'd have to take a an initial pass through the code, and you'd be out of the realm of pure python.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking that you haven't already answered yourself.  You can't have an earlier method call depend on a later one.  You can have all the calls pile up into a stack, and then have a "finish" operation that resolves them all, but you can't do that without an explicit "finish", for exactly the reason you mentioned: there's no way for a method to know if it is the last one in the chain.  (You don't need a separate line for the "finish", though; you could do `obj.a().b().c().finish()`.)

Comment: This is a typical ORM implementation pattern of chaining and "building up state".

Comment: @glaucon Would something like [this](https://repl.it/pVs/3) implement your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

you can implement `__iter__` method.

```
class ChainClassTest(object):

    ...

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in self.now_actually_do_it():
            yield i
```

this way, you would be able to do things like:

```
>>> my_list = list(cct.filter_by().order_by())
```

and

```
>>> for item in cct.filter_by().order_by():
...    print item
```

etc.

you can also implement:
 `__len__(self)` to support `len(cct.filter_by().order_by())`.
 `__getitem__(self,item)` to support `cct.filter_by().order_by()[34]`.

Comment: Also known as lazy loading/evaluation

Comment: This still executes `.get_list()` before `.filter_by()`. Because the evaluation is lazy you can have `.filter_by()` set a filter on `self` which is used by `.get_list()`, but then you have to reset that filter before calling `.get_list()` again. The object will retain a state which should only be a part of the method call. That's bad design and will lead to trouble.

Comment: The `get_list` was my mistake, I meant you don't need it and you can put iys logic in `__iter__`.  I fixed my answer

Comment: My comment is still valid no matter what the functions are called. ;-)

Comment: so I'm not sure I understand you, the OP want `filter_by()` to change the object behaviour

Comment: No, op wants filter_by() to change the behavior of get_list() (or __iter__()), IMO this is a fundamental mistake, he shouldn't do that, for the reason mentioned. It's bad design.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you want to have a chained type of calling, but then you can't return `self`, because then the `order_by()` is not acting on the filtered result set that `filter_by()` is creating, but it is acting on the original `cct` object.

Instead each method should return a result set, which also has method for adding filtering etc.

On the other hand, Python has builtins for most of that already:

```
filter(filter_fun, sorted(cct.get_list(), key=keyfun))
```

Therefore the only reason to do this is if you are actually building a query that is being deferred to a call to a library or a service call, yet again like with an ORM. In that case you should rather build up an object chain of filtering and ordering commands and return that, and then have that chain parsed and executed when called.

Returning `self` in the functions above is in any case hardly useful.

Unless of course you actually modify self in each call, but if you do that your chained calling API is going to be confusing. Modifying self will also
mean that the object retains a state that is not a part of the object, but of the calls. So you could for example have `.filter_by()` set a filter on the object, which is used by `.get_list()`. But then you have to reset that filter before you make a new `.get_list()` or the filter will still be active.

That's hard to use and brittle.